# Mostrar alerta cuando el usuario o la contraseña no sea correcta

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo que validar dos datos: Cedula y password. Tengo un required para cada campo y así obligo a que se tengan que llenar los campos pero no sé como mostrar un mensaje que indique si el usuario no existe o la contraseña es incorrecta, Espero su respuesta. Adjunto código html.

```html
<div class="modal-dialog text-center modal-sm shadow-lg">
        <div class="main-section">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="col-12 user-img">
                   <img src="../img/usuario.png" alt="usuario">
               </div>
                <form class="col-12" method="POST" id="formlg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cédula" id="cedula" name="cedula" required="" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="pass" name="pass" required="">
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-primary">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

lo que te puedo recomendar si estas utilizando pura y exclusivamente html, js y php es realizar previamente una consulta a la base de datos y almacenar los datos en un array y pasarselos a JS.

En principio vamos a agregarle a tus input el evento Onchange:
Al de usuario le asignaremos la funcion userCheck y al de pass la funcion passCheck.

`input onChange="userCheck()" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cédula" id="cedula" name="cedula" required="" autofocus>

<input onChange="passCheck()" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="pass" name="pass" required="">`

CODIGO PHP CONEXION A LA BASE:

`$servidor="localhost";
$nombreBd="nombrebd";
$usuario="root";
$pass="";
$conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$pass,$nombreBd);
if($conexion -> connect_error ){
    die("No se pudo conectar");
}

?>`

CODIGO PHP PARA HACER LAS CONSULTAS:

`//CONSULTAR LOS USUSARIOS Y ALMACENARLAS EN UN ARRAY:

$queryNombres = 'SELECT nombres from tabla';
$nombres = mysqli_query($conexion,$queryNombres);
$arrayNombres = array();
while($row = $nombres->fetch_assoc()){
 $arrayNombres[] = $row['nombreCampoUsuariosEnBD']
}

//CONSULTAR LAS CLAVES Y ALMACENARLAS EN UN ARRAY:


$queryPass = 'SELECT claves from tabla';
$pass = mysqli_query($conexion,$queryNombres);
$arrayPass = array();
while($row = $pass->fetch_assoc()){
 $arrayPass[] = $row['nombreCampoClavesEnBD']
}`

Ahora lo que vas a hacer en JAVASCRIPT es agarrar y convertir los array de PHP ($arrayNombres y $arrayPass) a JSON mediante la funcion de php json_encode:

`var dataNombres = <?php echo json_encode($arrayNombres); ?>
 var dataClaves= <?php echo json_encode($arrayPass); ?>

 //Ahora vas a poder acceder mediante las posiciones al array que contiene los datos   de tu base de datos, es decir vas a tener acceso a las claves y a los usuarios.

//Capturemos los valores de los input en tu formulario:
function userCheck(){
 let usuarioInput = documment.getElementById("cedula").value;
 
 if(!dataNombres.includes(usuarioInput)){
  window.alert("No existe el usuario");
 }
}

function passCheck(){
 let passInput= documment.getElementById("pass").value;
 
 if(!dataClaves.includes(passInput)){
  window.alert("Clave incorrecta");
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Algo muy simple:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login cedula</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./code.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal-dialog text-center modal-sm shadow-lg">
      <div class="main-section">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="col-12 user-img">
            <img src="../img/usuario.png" alt="usuario">
          </div>
          <form class="col-12" id="formlg" onSubmit="login()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cédula" id="cedula" name="cedula" required="" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="pass" name="pass" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div id="caja_mensaje"></div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Impedir que la pagina se recarge al darle a submit
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    const form = document.getElementById("formlg");
    function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
    form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);
});

// Funcion que gestiona el login y la llamada a servidor
function login() {
    const cajaMensaje = document.getElementById('caja_mensaje');
    const cedula = document.getElementById('cedula').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {  
            console.log(xmlhttp.status); 
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               cajaMensaje.innerHTML = 'contraseña correcta, redireccionando ...';
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.status == 401) {
              cajaMensaje.innerHTML = 'cedula o contraseña incorrectos';
            }
            else {
                cajaMensaje.innerHTML = 'Algo ha ido mal, intentelo de nuevo';
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "login.php", false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("cedula=" + cedula + "&password=" + password);
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

$correctCedula = 'cedula';
$correctPassword = '12345';

/* INPUTS */
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($cedula !== $correctCedula || $password !== $correctPassword) {
    return header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
} 

return header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
```

Comment: Mano gracias pero no funciona, la parte de "Impedir que la pagina se recargue al darle a submit" no deja que funcione cuando el usuario si es correcto

Comment: ¿Estas seguro? Esto lo he probado en mi localhost con wamp, el cliente hace una peticion ajax al php (sin recargar la pagina) y en funcion de la respuesta muestra un texto u otro. Si puedes decirme si lo has implementado a rajatabla o has cambiado algo, quizá tu no has mostrado un texto si no que has hecho otra cosa? Si me dices, te puedo ayudar

Comment: Solo estoy manejando php y Html